# How to connect SQL Server across the Work Network?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

SQL 2008:

I am trying to access SQL Database which is running on Server / Test Computer which has Windows XP OS.

My Computer and Test Computer both are connected in our Local Network.

Still I am not able to access the Test Computer.

**TITLE: Connect to Server**

Cannot connect to XP-BE301D36469F.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the 
operation or the server is not responding. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)
For help, click: http://go.Microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476
```

I can only click `OK` to dismiss the window.  How to fix this issue?

Actually, I am not able to connect either way .. I.e) To the Test Machine or from the Test Machine.

Comment: Are you using SQL Management studio to connect? Are you able to ping the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SQL Management Studio to connect to the database, then I would check the following on the machine running SQL Server:

- Are you able to ping between the 2 machines?
- Is the firewall disabled, or is TCP for port 1433 allowed?
- Is the SQL engine running?
- Are named pipe and TCP connections enabled inside SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I believe TCP is disabled by default in SQLServer. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on how to enable.